# Hibernate or h2 database adds 33 to a generated value after table switch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I have hibernate entities courses,users,etc. If i add something in one table it works fine. First then second and so on. But if i switch to another table it adds ~33 to an id column and begin to add rows with  id like 33 after 3d then 34 and so on. After every table switch it adds ~33 to a generated id. I'm using h2 database.
My entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSES")
public class Courses {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private int course_id;

    @Column(name = "course_name", nullable = false)
    private String courseName;
...
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int user_id;


    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
...
}
```

This is how i save new rows:

public void save(Courses course) {

```
   Session session = sf.openSession();
   Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
   session.save(course);
   session.flush();
   transaction.commit();
   session.close();
```

}

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i'm using h2 database.

Comment: What do you mean by "switch to another table"? And what dou you do with the sequence?